# getActionBar Showing null

Tags: java, android

```
 public class Main_Activity extends Fragment_Activity{

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
            pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
            ActionBar bar=getActionBar();

            if(getActionBar()!=null) {
                bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#4a90e2")));
            }


        }
```

I am using extends Fragment_Activity and i want action bar to be displayed but in my program getActionBar() is returning null

Comment: Are you sure you have to extend `Fragment_Activity`? Normally, `FragmentActivity` is used.

Comment: Check your manifest & style.xml to confirm that you are not using NoActionBar Style

Comment: Read: [ActionBar returning null](https://wenchaojames.wordpress.com/2013/01/16/getactionbar-returns-null/)

Answer (score 1):

As for the docs

If you want to implement an activity that includes an action bar, you should instead use the **ActionBarActivity** class, which is a subclass of this one, so allows you to use Fragment APIs on API level 7 and higher.

Change following line

```
public class Main_Activity extends Fragment_Activity
```

to

```
public class Main_Activity extends ActionBarActivity
```

and to get **ActionBar** call

```
 getSupportActionBar();
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Extend `ActionBarActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity.`

```
public class Main_Activity extends ActionBarActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        ActionBar bar=getActionBar();

        if(getActionBar()!=null) {
            bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#4a90e2")));
        }


    }
```

Comment: I am removing theme in Application Tag in Manifestfile

Answer (score 0):

try to get `ActionBar` with

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```